# Finding Root of Tree from List of Tuples

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree

I am having issues writing a function that finds the root of a tree represented as a list of tuples in python.

Tree:

```
[(39, 38), (80, 70), (39, 42), (80, 91), (37, 22), (37, 39), (42, 45), (48, 37), (91, 85), (48, 60), (60, 80), (60, 50)]
```

I researched how to use classes for this but not sure if there is any kind of clever way to do this.

Comment: What do you have so far, with regards to a solution? So we can help you with what you're specifically getting stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the tuple start that is not in any tuple end:

```
lst = [(39, 38), (80, 70), (39, 42), (80, 91), (37, 22), (37, 39), (42, 45), (48, 37), (91, 85), (48, 60), (60, 80), (60, 50)]

rt = set([t[0] for t in lst if not t[0] in [t[1] for t in lst]])

print(rt)  # nothing links to 48 so it must be the root
```

Output

```
{48}
```

You can assign the t[1] loop to a variable if desired:

```
lst1 = [t[1] for t in lst]  # all end nodes
rt = set([t[0] for t in lst if not t[0] in lst1])
```

Comment: Does the second for loop over t[1] need to be part of of the first for loop ? Isn't [t[1] for t in lst] static? If so, would the solution above recompute it unnecessarily  len(lst) times?

Comment: Yes - That list is static. I don't know if python will repeat the list generation each time. You can set it to a variable if speed is a concern. Answer updated.